# Wicket hacked use of ListView, which alternatives?

Tags: java, frameworks, wicket

Wicket use of models can be cumbersome. For a stateful page to properly render an object, you need to use lots of boiler-plate code, overriding classes to properly get the visibility status, etc... A simple example:

```
private IModel<FooBar> fooBarModel;
public MyPage() {
    Label lbl1 = new Label("field1",
               new PropertyModel<>(fooBarModel, "field1")) {
        @Override public boolean isVisible() {
             return fooBarModel.getObject().someCondition();
    }   }
    add(lbl1);
    /// Etc... same for dozen of other fields
}
```

I'm often using a trick using a `ListView` to help. Same example:

```
public MyPage() {
    add(new ListView<FooBar>("content",
                new SingleListModel<FooBar>(fooBarModel)) {
        @Override protected void populateItem(...) {
            FooBar fooBar = item.getModelObject();
            // Code here gets simpler:
            Label lbl1 = new Label("field1", fooBar.getField1());
            lbl1.setVisible(fooBar.someCondition());
            item.add(lbl1);
            // Etc...
        }
    });
}
```

With a simple utility class `SingleListModel`, that transform a `IModel<T>` to a `ListModel<T>`, having 1 or 0 elements, depending whether T is null or not:

```
public class SingleListModel<T>
extends LoadableDetachableModel<List<T>> {
    private IModel<T> tModel;
    public SingleListModel(IModel<T> tModel) {
        this.tModel = tModel;
    }
    @Override
    protected List<T> load() {
        List<T> ret = new ArrayList<>(1);
        T t = tModel.getObject();
        if (t != null)
            ret.add(tModel.getObject());
        return ret;
    }
}
```

The nice side-effect of this is that the whole "content" element in the markup is hidden if `fooBarModel` returns `null`; no special treatment needed.

But all this smells like a hack to me, as I use `ListView` in a somehow "unnatural" fashion.

**Is there a cleaner way to get the same result? A standard wicket framework?**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about working code belong on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Michael i don't think so . its look legit for me.

Comment: @soorapadman "What's a good way to do X?" is opinion-based.

Comment: I'm not really asking "the good way to do X", but a "cleaner way than X", X being a hack.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Behavior instead to avoid such duplications.

```
public class MyBehavior extends Behavior {

   private final MyModel model;

   public MyBehavior(MyModel model) {this.model = model;}

   @Override public void onConfigure(Component c) {
      if (model.someCondition()) {
        component.setVisible(false);
      }
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
MyBehavior b = new MyBehavior(modelInstance);
component1.add(b);
component2.add(b);
// dozen more
```

Comment: Thanks for this useful hint. But here my problem is not really about code duplication. I have many different objects and fields with many different visibility conditions, so this would need dozen of different behaviors for controlling visibility. The trick about using a ListView is to be able to create the view using code such as `setVisible(cond)` and `new Label("x", fooBar.getX())` without having to create dozen of models / behaviors / subclasses. Is this use of ListView has a cleaner pattern in Wicket?

Answer (score 0):

```
Label lbl1 = new Label("field1",
           new PropertyModel<>(fooBarModel, "field1")) {
    @Override public boolean isVisible() {
         return fooBarModel.getObject().someCondition();
}   }
add(lbl1);
```

with little refactoring it can be converted into

```
add(new FLabel("id","text")
        .setVisibilityFunction(()->model.getObject().isVisible()))
);
```

the FLabel class:

```
public class FLabel extends Label implements IComponentWithVisibilityFunction<FLabel> {

    private SerializableBooleanSupplier visibilityFunction;

    public FLabel(String id) {
        super(id);
    }

    public FLabel(String id, Serializable label) {
        super(id, label);
    }

    public FLabel(String id, IModel<?> model) {
        super(id, model);
    }

    @Override
    public FLabel setVisibilityFunction(SerializableBooleanSupplier visibilityFunction) {
        this.visibilityFunction = visibilityFunction;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onConfigure() {
        if (visibilityFunction != null) {
            setVisible(visibilityFunction.getAsBoolean());
        }
    }
}

public interface IComponentWithVisibilityFunction<T> {
    T setVisibilityFunction(SerializableBooleanSupplier visibilityFunction);
}
```

Moreover you can put supplier into constructor:

```
add(new FLabel("id","text", ()->model.getObject().isVisible()));
```

Comment: Thanks for all those answers, but that does not really answer my question. The original aim of my "hacked" use of ListView is to defer the creation of the various sub-components at page rendering time, not during page construction. The advantage of this method is that it prevent the use of many lambda / anonymous classes, and is probably more efficient. I was more asking if there was a standard component / way to do the same thing instead of using a ListView.